# Prove $2\mid n$ if, and only if, $2\mid r_0$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ with $n=r_0+r_1\cdot6+r_2\cdot6^2+\cdots+r_k\cdot6^k$.

Prove  $2\mid n$ if, and only if, $2\mid r_0$.

---

### What I tried:

Direct Proof:

If $2\mid r_0$ and $2\mid n$, then $r_0=2m$ and $n = 2n$, for some $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$

So $r_0x + ny = 2(mx + ny)$, with $mx+ny\in\mathbb{Z}$, which follows $2\mid (r_0x+ny)$

End of proof

- I was stuck on this question for so long and this is the closest/most reasonable way I think of doing this question. Is this correct or not? If not, how would I do this question? Note: You can use any proof, I just chose Direct Proof because I wasn't sure what to do.

Comment: Hint: $\ r + 6n\,$ is even $\iff r \,$ is even, i.e. $\bmod 2\!:\ r + 0\equiv 0\iff r\equiv 0\ \ \ $

Comment: Is my proof correct or what is wrong with my proof?

Comment: The first mistake in your proof is this: When you want to prove "X if and only if Y", starting by assuming both X and Y will get you nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your proof would work.

In particular, to prove $A \iff B$, we can't start the proof with suppose both $A$ and $B$ are both true.

The key idea is that $6$ is a multiple of $2$.

$$n-r_0=6(r_1+6r_2 + \ldots + 6^{k-1}r_k)$$

The right hand side is divisble by $2$, hence $n-r_0$ must be divisible by $2$ as well. That is they must share the same parity.

Comment: What type of proof would I use?

Comment: you can use a direct proof. assume one side, prove the other side then prove the reverse as well.

Answer (score 1):

A way to prove that just use the simple fact: 
If $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$, then $a\mid bm+cn$ for every $m,n\in\Bbb{Z}.$

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose that $2\mid n$. Since $2\mid 6$, from the fact mentioned earlier, we have that $2\mid r_1\cdot6+r_2\cdot6^2+\cdots+r_k\cdot6^k$. Hence $2\mid n-(r_1\cdot6+r_2\cdot6^2+\cdots+r_k\cdot6^k)$ and that is $2\mid r_0$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Reciprocally, suppose now that $2\mid r_0$. Since $2\mid6$ we have $2\mid r_1\cdot6+r_2\cdot6^2+\cdots+r_k\cdot6^k$, thus $2\mid r_0+(r_1\cdot6+r_2\cdot6^2+\cdots+r_k\cdot6^k)$, thus $2\mid n$.